# Security updates are set "download and update automatically" yet some security updates don't get installed

Tags: 14.04, security, automation

I am using kubuntu 14.04.2

I have updates set to download and update automatically for where there are security updates - yet the security update for Adobe Flash was not automatically installed when I look a day or two after its release. I had to manually install through the software updater.

It seems it isn't doing what is says it does "Download and install automatically"

I can live with other updates asking for permission - but not security updates.

Comment: Which package did you install `flashplugin-installer` or `adobe-flashplugin`?

Comment: I have flashplugin-installer installed. Though this may have been after I found that adobe had a serious security flaw and updated it. I'll have to keep an eye on it. Hopefully all is well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flashplugin-installer` package is in `trusty-security` section of repositories and it should be automatically installed.

But `adobe-flashplugin` package is not. It is in `partner` repository.

If you install `flashplugin-installer`, that should fix this issue.

You can also set up the system to automatically upgrade packages from other sections of Ubuntu repositories.

This setting is in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50-unattended-upgrades`

If you already clicked to "Download and install automatically" in GUI there must be an uncommented line

```
"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
```

If you uncomment the next line

```
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
```

by removing `//`, all updates should be downloaded and installed automatically.

There are also other settings in this file, that are well commented right there.

Comment: Could you propose a way in which this user could enable automatic updates for Flash? For instance an update script which could be run at intervals or at startup and perform this action.

Comment: I *feel* like this answer is factually incorrect (but currently lack the technical expertise to prove it outright). `flashplugin-installer` exists in `trusty/multiverse`, `trusty-updates/multiverse` *and* `trusty-updates/multiverse`. I would think the repo —not the section— would determine which updates are counted as security updates. Chrome is in its own repo, which is why its updates aren't automatically counted as security updates.

Comment: @Oli Why downvote, if you do not have "technical expertise"? I updated the answer with more details.

Comment: @Oli But you are correct that flashplugin is in `trusty-security`.